# How to open a BASH terminal from Visual Slick Edit?

Tags: bash, terminal, slickedit

**SlickEdit 2011 (v16.0.3.0 64-bit)**

**CentOS Linux release 7.6.1810 (Core)**

I put a custom button on my slickedit tool bar and put the command launch-os-shell in it.

When I click the button I get an error message in my status bar:

Quote

```
"xterm program not found"
```

How can I set up the custom button ( or the launch-os-shell  command ) to launch BASH and launch it in the directory of the buffer I am editing?

I tried setting both def_linux1_shell and def_linux2_shell to bash, but no change.

Answer (score 0):

CentOS doesn't have xterm installed by default.

The default desktop/window manger is GNOME, which is gnome-terminal.

So, the command I would want to use in my custom terminal button would be

```
xcom /usr/bin/gnome-terminal
```

To have it open in the directory of the current buffer

Macro -> Set Macro Variable

def_switchbuf_cd

to

2